# Can we limit searches by date?

Tags: support

I'm trying to figure out what my weather and world clock options are on my new laptop. Most of the posts I am surfacing about weather indicators are about `weather-indicator` which hasn't been updated since 2011 and the posts are typically at least 10 years old.

Is there a way to search for posts that are < 5 years old?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, there are ways to filter searches, but its limited.

Refer to https://askubuntu.com/help/searching for the large details.

Specifics include:

> **Dates**
>
> You can use specific dates or date ranges to narrow results down to
> posts created or active within a certain time period, using the
> following operators:
>
> - `created:` to specify when the posts were created
> - `lastactive:` for posts active in a specified time period
>
> Dates can be entered in the following formats:
>
> - Absolute dates:
>
>   - year only – e.g., `created:2012..2013` searches posts created from January 1, 2012 through December 31, 2013; `created:2012`
>     searches posts created from January 1, 2012 through December 31, 2012.
>     year and month – e.g., `created:2012-04..2012-05` searches posts created between April 1, 2012 and May 31, 2012.
>     day, month, and year – e.g., `lastactive:2012-04-03` searches posts who were last active between 12:00 AM on April 3, 2012 and 11:59
>     PM on April 3, 2012.
> - Relative dates:
>
>   - `1y`, `1m`, and `1d` are shorthand for "last year", "last month", and "yesterday" – e.g., if today is April 15, `created:1m`
>     searches posts created between March 1 and March 31. (You can
>     substitute any number for 1 to look back that many years, months, or
>     days.)
>   - Relative dates in a range (`1y..`) look back to the same date in the previous period – e.g., if you want to see all the posts active
>     in the last three months, use `lastactive:3m..` On April 15, that will
>     show posts from January 15 up to the most recently active. You can
>     close the range as well: `lastactive:3m..1m`.
>
> **Please note that all times are recorded in UTC; the results may not
> match your timezone.**